# AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', For handleGoogleLogin in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, google-cloud-platform

I have attempted to build sort of a base login page using Google Auth, following various instructions from various sources and I am facing a bit of a roadblock at the moment. I am running into an Axios error when running my react app when I attempt to login. The pop-up for google auth appears but this error appears in the console when I select an account to login with.

LoginPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './LoginPage.css';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import axios from 'axios'; 

function LoginPage() {
  const [emailToken, setEmailToken] = useState('');

  const handleGoogleLogin = async (accessToken) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback', { accessToken });

      const receivedEmailToken = response.data.emailToken;
      setEmailToken(receivedEmailToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login failed:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleUserDataFetch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/auth/user', {
        headers: { emailToken: emailToken },
      });

      const userData = response.data;
      console.log('User data:', userData);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100">
      <h1>HELLO</h1>
      <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="***FILLER***">
        <GoogleLogin
          onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
            const accessToken = credentialResponse.access_token;
            handleGoogleLogin(accessToken); 
          }}
          onError={() => {
            console.log('Login Failed');
          }}
        />
      </GoogleOAuthProvider>

      {emailToken && (
        <button onClick={handleUserDataFetch}>Fetch User Data</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Backend.js

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const UserModel = require('./models/User');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const tokenUtils = require('./utils/tokenUtils');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Initialize Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Configure Google OAuth
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: '***FILLER***',
      clientSecret: '***FILLER***',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {


      try {

        let user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value });

        if (!user) {

          user = await UserModel.create({
            email: profile.emails[0].value,

            emailToken: '',

          });
        }


        const emailToken = tokenUtils.generateEmailToken(profile.emails[0].value);


        user.emailToken = emailToken;
        await user.save();

        return done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);


app.get(
  'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {

    res.json({ message: 'Successfully authenticated with Google' });
  }
);



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

The clientID is filled with a filler instead of the actual clientID. Ive also tried removing the http://localhost:3000/ and re-adding it to ensure that the callbacks are consistent. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.